# Remote repository name is changed, updating the local repository to point to new named remote repo

Tags: git, github

The remote repository name was changed and I need to update my local repository to point this new remote  repository.
I tried setting the remote repo url like

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket<url to remote repo>.git
```

but this does not work
I tried using the intellij to update the project but I get

```
    fatal: remote error: Repository not found
The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to
access it.
```

if i try to fetch from the gitbash, I get the same message.
How to make the local repository point this name changed repo.

Comment: Is it possible the new repo has different permissions and now you don't have access?

Answer (score 0):

Test first your authentication:

```
ssh -Tv ssh://git@bitbucket
```

Then double/check the SSH URL

```
ssh://git@bitbucket/aUser/aRepository.git
```

(The URL is case-sensitive)

Finally, as commented, check you are the owner or user with the [right repository access](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/grant-repository-access-to-users-and-groups/).